# Sobreponer un div con otro

Tags: css, fullcalendar, tailwind

Buen dias compañeros este es mi primer pregunta y espero no este mal, me encontraba haciendo un modal usando tailwind y js, como pueden ver en la imagen de abajo por alguna razon no se sobreponia el modal y me dejaba interactuar con el calendario (fullcalendar), despues de muchos intentos lo "solucione" aplicandole 'invisible' al calendario al momento de abrir el modal pero mi duda es que es lo que sucedio ahi si alguien me puede explicar, les comparto el codigo que tenia y muchas gracias de antemano :D

[image: Resultado]

```js
const button = document.getElementById('buttonmodal')
const closebutton = document.getElementById('closebutton')
const modal = document.getElementById('modal')
const calcont = document.getElementById('cal-container')


button.addEventListener('click',openModal)
closebutton.addEventListener('click',closeModal)

function openModal(){
    calcont.classList.add('invisible')
    modal.classList.add('scale-100')
}

function closeModal(){
    modal.classList.remove('scale-100')
    calcont.classList.remove('invisible')
}
```

```html
<div id="cal-container" class="m-56 visible">
    <div id="calendar" style="max-width: 500px"></div>
</div>

<div>
    <button id="buttonmodal" type="button">Abre modal</button>
</div>

<div id="modal"
    class="fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-blue-500 bg-opacity-50 transform scale-0 transition-transform duration-300">
    <div class="z-50 bg-white w-1/2 h-1/2 p-12"> 
        <button id="closebutton" type="button" class="focus:outline-none">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                    d="M10 14l2-2m0 0l2-2m-2 2l-2-2m2 2l2 2m7-2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
            </svg>
        </button>
        <form action="{{route('store.estudiante')}}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <label for="name">Ingresa tu nombre</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="nombre">
            <br>
            <label for="ncontrol">Ingresa tu numero de control</label>
            <input id="ncontrol" type="text" name="control">
            <br>
            <label for="date">Elige el dia</label>
            <input id="date" type="date" name="fecha">
            <br>
            <label for="hour">Elige la hora</label>
            <input id="hour" type="time" name="hora">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar formulario">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```